# d3.js reverse transition does not work

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, transform

I am working on horizontal segment bar chart. I want to make it so that the bar chart will animate the colour transition between individual segments depending on the value that is generated randomly every few seconds.

I also have a text box that at the moment says "hello" and it is moving simultaneously with the transition.It works only in one direction from left to right.
I cannot make the colour transition between segments and translating the text box from left to right. From left to right I mean that the number generated last time is greater than the currently generated number. The bar chart should turn  off the segments from right to left. But it does it from left to right also the text box is acting weirdly when it comes to reverse translation.

I am also getting this error: g attribute transform: Expected transform function, "null". In my code I want to make a transition on my valueLabel and I think the way I am using is not correct. Despite this error the code gets executed.
My fiddle code is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/milka22/n9wnjbk5/7/)

Many thanks for suggestions

```
var configObject = {

    svgWidth : 1000,
    svgHeight : 1000,


    minValue : 1,
    maxValue : 100,

    midRange : 50,
    highRange : 75,

    numberOfSegments : 50
};
//define variables
var newValue;
var gaugeValue = configObject.minValue - 1;
var mySegmentMappingScale;
var rectArray=[];


//define svg
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", configObject.svgWidth)
    .attr("height", configObject.svgHeight)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", 'translate(' + configObject.svgWidth/2 + ',' + configObject.svgHeight/2 + ')');

//var myG=svg.append('g');
var valueLabel= svg.append("text")
    .attr('x',0)
    .attr('y', (configObject.svgHeight/13)+15)
    .text("hello");

var backgroundRect=svg.append("rect")
    .attr("fill", "black")
    .attr("x",0) 
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", (configObject.svgWidth/3))
    .attr("height",  configObject.svgHeight/13);

for(i = 0; i <= configObject.numberOfSegments; i++){
    var myRect=svg.append("rect")
        .attr("fill", "#2D2D2D")
        .attr("x",i * ((configObject.svgWidth/3)/configObject.numberOfSegments)) 
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("id","rect"+i)
        .attr("width", ((configObject.svgWidth/3)/configObject.numberOfSegments)-3)
        .attr("height",  configObject.svgHeight/13);    

         rectArray.push(myRect);

    }
//define scale
function setmySegmentMappingScale(){
        var domainArray = [];
        var x=0;
        for(i = configObject.minValue; i <= configObject.maxValue+1; i = i + (configObject.maxValue - configObject.minValue)/configObject.numberOfSegments){
          if(Math.floor(i) != domainArray[x-1]){ 
               var temp=Math.floor(i);
               domainArray.push(Math.floor(i));
               x++;
           }
       }

        var rangeArray = [];
        for(i = 0; i <= configObject.numberOfSegments+1; i++){//  <=
            rangeArray.push(i);
        }
        mySegmentMappingScale = d3.scale.threshold().domain(domainArray).range(rangeArray);

    }

//generate random number
function generate(){
    var randomNumber = Math.random() * (configObject.maxValue - configObject.minValue) + configObject.minValue;     
    newValue = Math.floor(randomNumber);
    setmySegmentMappingScale(); 
    animateSVG();
}     
function animateSVG(){

var previousSegment = mySegmentMappingScale(gaugeValue) -1;
var newSegment = mySegmentMappingScale(newValue) -1;

    if(previousSegment <= -1 && newSegment > -1){
        for(i = 0; i <= newSegment; i++){ 

            rectArray[i].transition()
                .ease("linear")
                .duration(50)
                .delay(function(d){return i * 90})
                .styleTween("fill", function() { return d3.interpolate( "#2D2D2D","red"); });

                valueLabel
                .transition().ease("linear")
                .duration(50)
                .delay(function(d){return i * 90})
                .attr("transform","translate(" + (i * ((configObject.svgWidth/3)/configObject.numberOfSegments)+((configObject.svgWidth/3)/configObject.numberOfSegments)) + "," + 0 + ")")


        }
    }
    else if(newSegment > previousSegment){

        for(i = previousSegment; i <= newSegment; i++){
            rectArray[i].transition()
                        .ease("linear")
                        .duration(50)
                        .delay(function(d){return i * 90})
                         .styleTween("fill", function() { return d3.interpolate( "#2D2D2D","red"); });
            //console.log(temp);
            valueLabel
            .transition()
            .ease("linear")
            .duration(50)
            .delay(function(d){return i * 90})
            .attr("transform","translate(" + (i * ((configObject.svgWidth/3)/configObject.numberOfSegments)+((configObject.svgWidth/3)/configObject.numberOfSegments)) + "," + 0 + ")")




        }
    }
    else if(newSegment < previousSegment){

        for(i = previousSegment; i > newSegment; i--){

            rectArray[i].transition()
                        .ease("linear")
                        .duration(50)
                        .delay(function(d){return i * 90})
                        .styleTween("fill", function() { return d3.interpolate( "red","#2D2D2D"); });


                        valueLabel
                        .transition()
                        .ease("linear")
                        .duration(50)
                        .delay(function(d){return i * 90})
                        .attr("transform","translate(" + (i * ((configObject.svgWidth/3)/configObject.numberOfSegments)-((configObject.svgWidth/3)/configObject.numberOfSegments)) + "," + 0 + ")")

        }
    }   
     gaugeValue = newValue;

}
setInterval(function() {
    generate()
}, 8000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is just the `delay`.

When `newSegment > previousSegment`, you set the delay like this:

```
.delay(function(d){return i * 90})
```

Which makes sense, because `i` is an increasing variable. But, when `newSegment < previousSegment` the same math doesn't work anymore: `i` is a decreasing variable, and the delay has to increase as `i` *decreases*, not the other way around.

This is what you need:

```
.delay(function(d){return Math.abs(i -previousSegment)*90})
```

Here is your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b7usw2nr/